# Bash check for repeated values in csv file

Tags: linux, bash

I have a file containing the following data

```
1:aaa:aaa:aaaa
2:bbb:dddd:aaaa
25:true:asd:asdf
```

and I want to append a line of the same structure on condition that the first field is no repeated. Example

```
11:ccc:ccc:aaaa can append
2:fff:ffff:ffff can not append
```

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do. Can you try to improve the explanation?

Comment: In the first line of your example, most people on SO would consider the first field to be '11' and the second field to be 'ccc', so that does not look like it is repeated, so it is ok to append. But on the second line, the 'fff' is not a repeat of the '2', so why can't we append to that? And what do you want appended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) :

```
awk -F: '($2 != $3 && $3 != $4){print $0":foobar"}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this function to check and it worked for me

```
func_is_pk(){
    if cut -d: -f"$2" "$l_user_name/$DBNAME/$t_name" | grep -x "^$1"
    then
        return 1
    else
        return 0
    fi
}
```